# A Poisson joint distribution MLE problem.

Tags: probability

Given a constants $\theta \ge 0$, and independent random variables $X_i \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda=1)$ where $i=1, 2, ... N$.

I want to find the any values of $\theta_i \ge 0$ that maximizes the likelihood $P(c_1 X_1 \le \theta_1, c_2 X_2 \le \theta_2, ... c_N X_N \le \theta_N)$ with the constraints $\sum_1^N \theta_i = \theta$, where $c_i$ are positive constants.

Comment: That looks difficult analytically, especially since the $X_i$ are only interesting when they take integer values.  It might therefore be sensible to make the constraint $\sum_1^N \theta_i \le \theta$

Comment: @Henry I see, it is actually a problem I encountered in my research, I spend hours thinking about it. I am wondering if there is any method that is suitable for this problem, so it is quite possible not feasible to tackle. Anyway, thank you for your comment here!

Comment: Have you ever tried to use the incomplete gamma integral to study the CDFs? E.g. perhaps considering $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \int_1^{+\infty} x^{\theta_i/c_i - 1}e^{-x}dx$ could give you some insight - but you probably still need to tackle the floor/ceiling function ultimately, as suggested by Henry.